# 504 gateway error in Springboot application due to non access of the web URL for sometime

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, cloud-foundry

I'm facing 504 gateway error in Spring boot application deployed in cloud foundry,when I don't access the WEB URL for sometime and refresh the page. Its a web application build on top of Spring Boot and Deployed in Cloud Foundry. Could you please suggest me why I am getting the issue and how can I fix it.

Note: Oracle DB has been used for data storage and SQL queries are used to Query the data from DB. We are restarting the service when ever 504 gateway error has thrown in order to bring up the service.

Logs

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------2018-06-20T11:58:30.190+02:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2018-06-20 09:58:30.190 ERROR 17 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception

2018-06-20T11:58:30.190+02:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 504 Gateway Time-out

2018-06-20T11:58:30.190+02:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)

2018-06-20T11:58:30.190+02:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)

2018-06-20T11:58:30.190+02:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)

2018-06-20T11:58:30.190+02:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:621)

2018-06-20T11:58:30.190+02:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:295)
```

Comment: Can you check the application logs?

Comment: Updated the logs.

Comment: The error looks like it's just a message saying your client got a 504 talking to some REST endpoint.  You need to look at the REST endpoint  you're trying to talk to and see why it, or something in between like a reverse proxy, is giving a 504.  At the same time, check if your HTTP client is doing connection pooling.  In some cases, pooled connections can be closed without informing the client.  The client tries to reused the connection which no longer exists and you get weird timeout issues.

Comment: Even without Rest endpoint, Im getting the same error. As per my understanding there is nothing to do with client. According to you if I place the same URL in new browser I should get the response. But still im getting the same error. Kindly suggest.